# MySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE and User Defined Variables

Tags: mysql, sql, into-outfile

Any idea why this fails in MySQL 5.1:

```
SET @LOAD_TIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
SET @OUTFILE = CONCAT(CONCAT('/tmp/outfile_', @LOAD_TIME), '.sql');

SELECT *
FROM `tableA`
INTO OUTFILE @OUTFILE;
```

Is it a limitation of MySQL's SELECT or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can't use a variable for the filename. like LIMIT, it must be a literal value, not a formula or a variable.

for example, what filename is the file going to be written to here?

```
SET @LOAD_TIME = UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
SET @OUTFILE = CONCAT(CONCAT('/tmp/outfile_', @LOAD_TIME), '.sql');

SELECT @OUTFILE = columnA
, columnB
FROM `tableA`
INTO OUTFILE @OUTFILE;
```

this is a similar restriction to the one on LIMIT. if expressions were allowed in LIMIT clauses, you could come up with queries that have unpredictable behavior. for example, say you have a table with 10 rows and column a has the values of 1 through 10. what's the output of this query?

```
SELECT *
  FROM myTable
ORDER
    BY a
 LIMIT 10 - a
```

the basis for this limitation is: if you can calculate the limit, then you should explicitly calculate the limit and then build the query with the literal value. allowing expressions like `10 - a` to be evaluated makes the query execution plan potentially MUCH more complicated.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered if no one else responds, but I'm wondering why.  Is it definitionally so or is it just a quirk of implementation or something?

Comment: i've expanded my answer above to explain why.

Comment: @longneck I am trying to use the first part of your code in the answer but I am receiving `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@OUTFILE' at line 5` any idea why?

Comment: You missed the point of my answer. What you are doing is not possible. My code is an example of why it's not possible.